# Receive Matlab/simulink UDP blocks in other software

Tags: eclipse, matlab, udp, xpc-target

Can we send Matlab/Simulink UDP blocks to other software like eclipse ? could eclipse read/use that for building android apps ? How should I do that ?

when sending data through UDP Send block of an xPC target it packed in binary I think , how can we on pack that in eclipse?

Comment: i think simulink can produce c++, then you can use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply built a simulink model and used udp send blocks to send the data . then in eclipse I wrote a client side to get the data from server and convert it from binary to ascii